# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF form that has some buttons to save user input, delete, and cancel. I was trying to add functionality such that whenever the user clicks the cancel button, there is a pop up a message. Instead it throws an exception in my controller:

```
"The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties"
```

Here is my view:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0">                        
    <Button Name="DeleteButton" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedStory}"  Cursor="Hand" Height="25" IsEnabled="{Binding CanDelete}" Margin="5 0 0 0">Delete</Button>
    <Button Name="SubmitButton" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedStory}"  Cursor="Hand" Height="25"  Margin="5 0 0 0">Submit</Button>
    <Button Name="CancelButton" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedStory}"  Cursor="Hand" Height="25" Margin="5 0 0 0" >Cancel</Button>
 </StackPanel>
```

My controller code:

```
    public MetadataController(IGatewayService gateway, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IDialogService dialog)
    {
        this.gateway = gateway;
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.dialog = dialog;

        // commands            
        this.CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand<StoryItem>(this.Close);//here i got the exception throwing "the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties"
        this.DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand<StoryItem>(this.Delete);
        this.SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand<StoryItem>(this.Submit, this.HasFieldsRequiredBeforeSubmit);

        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<StorySelectedEvent>().Subscribe(OnStorySelected);
    }

    private void Close(StoryItem selsectedStory)//when i click my close button its not calling this method at all.
    {
        bool isConfirmed = this.dialog.ShowConfirmation("Are you sure you want to close?");
    }

    private void Delete(StoryItem selectedStory)
    {
        bool isConfirmed = this.dialog.ShowConfirmation("Are you sure you want to permanently delete ?");

        if (isConfirmed)
        {
            this.gateway.DeleteStoryItem(selectedStory);

            this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<CommandCompletedEvent>().Publish(CommandTypes.MetadataEntry);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry ,my bad already i have another method in the same class that's why it throws that exception,now its working the way expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the exception ,i do have the method already and i was trying to create one,that's why it throws that error.Thanks lot for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

The exception you're getting indicates that it doesn't how to access whatever method/property you're attempting to call. Perhaps there is some other method or property that is also called `Close` or `CloseCommand` and is causing the conflict?

Comment: Sorry,forgot to changed the close method,upper case 'C'.In my code its UpperCase 'C' but i have the error throws @ this.CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand<StoryItem>(this.Close);//here i got the exception throwing "the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties"